# JQuery Functions are not Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript and a HTML file that utilise few functions in an external jQuery file (`jquery.myfile.min.js`). However, the functions written in `jquery.myfile.min.js` are not being executed.

I used the browser console and got this message:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'jQuery.myfile.validateData')`

I checked the resources the file has been loaded successfully in the website. What could possibly wrong here?

My code to call is

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
    if (jQuery.myfile.validateData(data) === true) {
        ...
    }
} 
</script>
```

My jQuery file `jquery.myfile.min.js` looks something like this:

```
(function() {

t = jQuery, t.myfile = {}, t.myfile.fn = {}, t.fn.myfile = function() {

..
.
...

t.myfile.validateData = function(t) {
    var n, r;
    ...<some logic>...
    return 1
}

}})
```

Thanks

Comment: why you use "j(document)" for jquery while in the function you use "jQuery" again but not "j"?

Comment: This works! But when I need to call a function that needs a parameter to work on, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is supposed to be supplying the `myfile` property on the result of a jQuery selector. (Is that supposed to be provided by your JS file? I can't tell from your question if that's code you wrote to extend jQuery or if it's just the standard jQuery.)

Accessing a property that doesn't exist results in `undefined`.

So, in this line:

```
jQuery('#my_variable').myfile('formatText');
```

...`.myfile` is undefined. So `.myfile('formatText')` is not a function.

This is why, in that line, you are getting the error `undefined is not a function`.

Comment: So how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, write it again without chaining like this

```
var query = jQuery('#my_variable');
var myFile = query.myfile('formatText');
```

Debug it and check where the error comes from. I suppose the error comes from  "myFile". Also, you should give more information about your code. You might make a mistake while extending.